# How do I setup a Criteria in nHibernate to query against multiple values

Tags: .net, nhibernate, criteria

I want to query for a set of results based on the contents of a list, I've managed to do this for a single instance of the class `Foo`, but I'm unsure how I would do this for a `IList<Foo>`.

So for a single instance of the class `Foo`, this works:

```
        public ICriteria CreateCriteria(Foo foo)
        {
            return session
                .CreateCriteria<Component>()
                .CreateCriteria("Versions")
                .CreateCriteria("PublishedEvents")
                .Add(Restrictions.And(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Name", foo.Name, MatchMode.Anywhere),
                                      Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Type", foo.Type, MatchMode.Anywhere)))
                .SetCacheable(true);
        }
```

But how do I do this when the method parameter is a list of `Foo`?

```
 public ICriteria CreateCriteria(IList<Foo> foos)
    {
        return session
            .CreateCriteria<Component>()
            .CreateCriteria("Versions")
            .CreateCriteria("PublishedEvents")
            .Add(Restrictions.And(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Name", foo.Name, MatchMode.Anywhere),
                                  Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Type", foo.Type, MatchMode.Anywhere)))
            .SetCacheable(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking about what you're trying to do with this query, it doesn't actually make sense to query it in the construct you're using. The only option you really have is to loop through and dynamically create the criteria like so:

```
 public ICriteria CreateCriteria(IList<Foo> foos)
    {
        var criteria = session
            .CreateCriteria<Component>()
            .CreateCriteria("Versions")
            .CreateCriteria("PublishedEvents")
            .SetCacheable(true);

        foreach(var foo in foos)
        {
            criteria.Add(Restrictions.And(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Name", foo.Name, MatchMode.Anywhere),Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Type", foo.Type, MatchMode.Anywhere)));
        }
        return criteria;
    }
```

Comment: is there a better way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: the only alternative is to use Restrictions.In() and pass in the collection, but since you're doing an InsensitiveLike, then you need to append each query. If you write the actual SQL you'd need to make this request the above approach makes perfect sense.